# How an entropy can be used to cluster a stocks in stock market?

Tags: entropy

Recently when I read reviews in entropy and its application in share market. I found the concept of entropy and clustering is not actively used in stock  market analysis. I think the clustering stocks brings out a great insights for investors and would like to apply this concept with stock market.so how is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

What is your motivation to focus on entropy? Which one? The concept of entropy and information theoretic clustering is subsumed by [information geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_geometry) clustering. As far as clustering financial assets is concerned, you can have a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00976.pdf) or [this one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4615.pdf) which focus on filtering the correlation matrix using clustering.

> I think the clustering stocks brings out a great insights for investors and would like to apply this concept with stock market.so how is it possible.

Indeed, [some hedge funds do that for instance](https://www.helleborecapital.com/), you can see some clustering results and their visualizations online [there](https://www.datagrapple.com/).